# UninitializedPropertyAccessException when using Hilt

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

Im getting `lateinit` error but I dont see the issue

```
 kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property soldatDatabase has not been initialized
        at pl.rybson.soldatlobby.di.RoomModule.provideServersDao(RoomModule.kt:37)
        at pl.rybson.soldatlobby.di.RoomModule_ProvideServersDaoFactory.provideServersDao(RoomModule_ProvideServersDaoFactory.java:27)
        at pl.rybson.soldatlobby.DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.getServersDao(DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.java:113)
        at pl.rybson.soldatlobby.DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.getMainRepository(DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.java:127)
        at pl.rybson.soldatlobby.DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.access$1800(DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.java:53)
        at pl.rybson.soldatlobby.DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerBaseApplication_HiltComponents_ApplicationC.java:431)
        at pl.rybson.soldatlobby.ui.home.HomeViewModel_AssistedFactory.create(HomeViewModel_AssistedFactory.java:24)
        at pl.rybson.soldatlobby.ui.home.HomeViewModel_AssistedFactory.create(HomeViewModel_AssistedFactory.java:12)
```

and the Module.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object RoomModule {

    private lateinit var soldatDatabase: SoldatDatabase

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRoom(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SoldatDatabase {
        soldatDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            SoldatDatabase::class.java,
            "soldat.db"
        )
            .build()
        return soldatDatabase
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideServersDao(): ServersDao {
        return soldatDatabase.serversDao()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dagger only creates dependencies if they are needed.  Since `provideServersDao` takes no arguments, Dagger concludes that `ServersDao` can be provided without any dependencies, and there is no reason to call `provideRoom`.

Since `ServersDao` actually depends on an instance of `SoldatDatabase`, you should ask Dagger to provide one for you:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object RoomModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRoom(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SoldatDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            SoldatDatabase::class.java,
            "soldat.db"
        )
            .build()
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideServersDao(soldatDatabase: SoldatDatabase): ServersDao {
        return soldatDatabase.serversDao()
    }

}
```

Comment: Ahhh. That's true. Thanks!